# Why does tabbed plots remove my title and labels?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created two figures which contains a new tab for each plot.
However only Figure2 contains "title" and "labels" on the plot and it also contains the "legend" which should have been on Figure1 - tab2.
Any suggestions why this happens?

```
figure_handles(1).mainfig = figure;
figure_handles(1).tabgroup = uitabgroup;
figure_handles(2).mainfig = figure;
figure_handles(2).tabgroup = uitabgroup;

% Fig1, tab1
newtab = uitab(figure_handles(1).tabgroup, 'Title', "tab1");
ax1 = axes(newtab); 
plot(ax1,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
title('FIG 1')
xlabel('X label')
ylabel('Y label')

% Fig2, tab1
newtab = uitab(figure_handles(2).tabgroup, 'Title', "tab1");
ax = axes(newtab); 
plot(ax,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
title('FIG 2')
xlabel('X label')
ylabel('Y label')

% Fig1, tab2 with legend
newtab = uitab(figure_handles(1).tabgroup, 'Title', "tab2");
ax3 = axes(newtab);
plot(ax3,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
hold on
plot(ax3,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
legend('1', '2')
title('FIG 1')
xlabel('X label')
ylabel('Y label')
hold off
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is pretty clear (but it took me a moment to realize it^^). 
The last tab that you are opening is from `figure_handle(2)`. So this is active. Everything that you draw without specifying an axis comes to this figure... So you are overdrawing this figure/tab/whatever.

Specifying the axis that you want those things to appear will sovle your problem (I shortend your variable names just for me to better follow the code)

```
fh = struct();
fh(1).fig = figure;
fh(1).tbgrp = uitabgroup;
fh(2).fig = figure;
fh(2).tbgrp = uitabgroup;

% Fig1, tab1
newtab = uitab(fh(1).tbgrp, 'Title', "tab1");
ax1 = axes(newtab); 
plot(ax1,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
title(ax1,'FIG 1')
xlabel(ax1,'X label')
ylabel(ax1,'Y label')


% Fig2, tab1
newtab = uitab(fh(2).tbgrp, 'Title', "tab1");
ax2 = axes(newtab); 
plot(ax2,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
title(ax2,'FIG 2')
xlabel(ax2,'X label')
ylabel(ax2,'Y label')

% Fig1, tab2 with legend
newtab = uitab(fh(1).tbgrp, 'Title', "tab2");
ax3 = axes(newtab);
plot(ax3,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
hold(ax3, 'on')
plot(ax3,rand(1,100)*10,rand(1,100)*10);
legend(ax3,'1', '2')
title(ax3,'FIG 1')
xlabel(ax3,'X label')
ylabel(ax3,'Y label')
hold(ax3, 'off')
```